# How to show notification bar if there is a new post in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want an alert bar at the top of my WordPress website, when there is a new post published on my blog. So the users are known that there is a new post available.

So I downloaded a WordPress plugin called: WPFront Notification Bar
Only the problem is that I only can set this bar on or off. But not show this bar automatically when there is a new post and after a day it will reset the value to off and will only be switched back to on if there is a hole new post.

So I thought if I make in my `header.php` a notification bar like the plugin, style it to my website and add some javascript to it. Only the problem is, I don’t know how to do this and also can’t find something on the internet so the reason for this question is written above.

Comment: I would try to add a time flag to the plugins options, set it when turning on / creating a new post and conditionally compare it when it is rendered. To only show it 24 hours after start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve that with a little code vs a plugin.

Modify a template (of a child theme preferably) it might be page.php or header.php, depends on your theme.  Add a function to functions.php to query for # of posts since whatever time you want your window to be.  If posts are returned  output html to create the alert bar styled to your taste; you could display the post count if you want to.

EDIT:
I modified your code below. [get_post_types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) accepts three parameters.  You provided the first, the other two are optional.  The third parameter $operator defaults to 'and'.  You ware asking for a list of post types that are public AND are not built-in type; that will only return you CPTs.  Adding the 2nd and 3rd param below asks for posts type that are public OR not built-in.

```
$args = array(
    'public'   => true,
    '_builtin' => false
);

$output = 'names'; // default = 'names'
$operator = 'or';  // default = 'and'

$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );

foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {

    echo '<p>' . $post_type . '</p>';

   $args = array( 'numberposts' => '1', 'post_type' => $post_type); // replace n with the number of posts
   $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

   foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
       echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="' . $recent["post_title"] . '" >' .   $recent["post_title"] . '</a>';
   }

}
```

The code above will return:

```
Array
    (
        [post] => post
        [page] => page
        [attachment] => attachment
        [my-cpt] => my-cpt
    )
```

Assuming you don't want to return pages or attachments, but just want the built-in 'post' and your custom post types you can skip the call to get_post_types and just create an array to suit your needs:

```
$post_types = array( 'post', 'my-cpt' );
```

If you don’t always know the name of CPTs (i.e. created by plugins), or you have many CPTs you can call get_post_types just as you were then add 'post' to the $post_types array.

```
$args = array(
    'public'   => true,
    '_builtin' => false
);
$post_types = get_post_types( $args );
$post_types['post'] = 'post';
```

Comment: I have some similair code made yesterday. I will post it later this day.

Comment: As I said in the morning, I had some similar code, but can’t get it right. I came up with the following: http://snippi.com/s/97csrlj 
This code will (for now) display all custom post types (only not the default post type of Wordpress) and the latest post of them. I think this is where you point out your answer, only this isn’t what you suggest. Hope you can help me further with my code to realize your answer :) Look out to your response! Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Thank you for above answer. Now all the last posts where displayed on my screen and I can select only the ones that I want. So as you said I also should know when the bar should be displayed and when not. I now trying to get the post date with: `the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ` but this will return for all posts the same date. Also I don’t know if this is the correct way to determine when the alert should be displayed. Hope you can help me a little further. I will check in the meantime for other solutions to get this fixed!

Comment: I came up with the following: http://snippi.com/s/6cm9n1b This will return the amount of posts of each post type. Only left is to compare the previous amount with the new result. Do you know how?

Comment: Hello Caspert, `the_time();` can only be used within the loop; the format defaults to the WordPress format, so you shouldn't need `get_option()`.  I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean when you refer to "compare the previous amount with the new result".

Comment: It seems like your initial problem is solved.  If so, please accept this as correct answer and begin another question explaining what you still want to accomplish and include the code you are using in the question. It's easier to look at the code and the question together in the SO post.  Thanks